# Portfolio has missing HTTP response

Tags: google-analytics

To my portfolio I had Google Universal Analytics, now it says "Error: No HTTP response detected", and I've tried to use Google Classic Analytics instead.

This site name is: www.henrikbaecklund.se

What should I do? What's interfering? It worked only a day ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page appears to be tracking:

[image]

Have you fixed something since you've posted?

Comment: I found out that I had a Google Chrome extension that blocks me from being tracked, so that's why it didn't work. Tried it from friends laptop and it worked,, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong, just had an unknown extension traffic blocker.

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off Chrome extension "Google Analytics Opt-out".